# Can two-pole brushed DC motors have a ring magnet stator?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is it possible to build a brushed DC motor with a ring magnet stator, instead of a stator with gaps as shown in the GIF below?

[image]

Comment: That looks just like a motor with a commutator.

Comment: yes brushed DC motors are motors with a commutator, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor#Brushed

Comment: I am interested in if they can have a closed ring stator

Comment: Deaw a diagram of what you mean, because so far, it is confusing.

Comment: just if there are brushed DC motors, like these, with a closed ring stator,
https://www.google.com/search?q=two-pole+brushed+dc+motor&tbm=isch

Comment: Update your question with a diagram - not chasing stuff in google

Comment: as you see in this image for example the stator tends to not be a closed ring. I am interested if there are versions with closed rings, or if it is possible to use closed ring stators overall,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor#/media/File:Electric_motor_cycle_2.png

Comment: in the question there is now an image, the stator there is almost a ring magnet, but not completely. I am interested in if it is possible to use a ring magnet as stator

Comment: added a GIF as well. as you see, the stator is not a complete ring magnet, it has two gaps. I am wondering if it would work just as well with a ring magnet, or if the magnetic field would somehow work less well.

Comment: Nope, because the commutators will be short circuited. it won't work. Then you have the brushes always in contact or commutation time goes to infinity.

Comment: Oh yes, that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: What I was actually interested in, but asking from another perspective, I have been told that the polarity somehow reverses on the inside of a ring magnet, cylindrical magnet, or sphere. Just from looking at a simple electric motor that seems inaccurate.

Comment: So maybe I could ask that, if the rotor in the GIF was just a permanent magnet, without any commutator or electric circuit, and the stator a ring magnet, would it still attract and repel at the same points it does in the GIF?

Comment: also does the commutator make contact with the stator? seems like it would need to do so to short circuit just because the stator was a ring magnet (without gaps)

Comment: You keep on adding questions in your comments. Please think carefully about what you would like to ask and then make one [edit] to your question. Please don't keep asking separate questions. If you have more specific questions, create another question so that each question post is on one topic only.

Comment: "does the commutator make contact with the stator" is not a new question, it is an attempt to understand the answer to the question, which has been given in comment form (i.e. not as an answer). I do not entirely see how the coil would short circuit otherwise.

Comment: just looking at images and gifs of brushed DC motors, the stator does not look like it makes contact with the rotor or the circuit that creates the magnetic field of the rotor. so, since the answer that has been given is "the stator is not enclosed because short circuit", I ask in reply "do the stator and rotor touch each other, i.e. could the stator shape actually short circuit the machine?"

Comment: it seems actually that @SamFarjamirad answered why the _commutator_ cannot be enclosed. maybe I am missing something @hazzey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to [your other question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28291/are-stator-magnets-in-brushed-dc-motors-radially-magnetised).

Yes, it is possible, and since permanent magnet DC motors have been around for well over 100 years, it's undoubtedly been done.  There are many downsides:

- It would be difficult to magnetize such a magnet to be as powerful as a pair of correctly-magnetized magnets
- Magnetic materials -- even steels -- are brittle, hard to machine, and won't have thermal expansion characteristics that match whatever you want to use for a case.

  - So getting one to match the size of the case would be difficult.
  - And Once you got your magnet machined to match the case at room temperature, chances are low that it would *stay* matched, because of differences in thermal expansion coefficients.
  - This, in turn, means that you can't press the magnet and case together -- you'd need to assemble them with glue or clips.
  - And all of that means that except in very specific circumstances, a full-ring magnet would be *more* expensive, *more* trouble, *less* reliable, and very likely lower performance than a "traditional" arrangement.

Comment: Hmmm, Do you have any source, pictures or an example? I believe this is not possible, but i have seen many unusual things in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but most available ring magnets will not work because they are made magnetised with opposite magnetic poles on opposite faces. This is called "axially magnetised". What you will need to find is a ring magnet with opposite magnetic poles on opposite halves of the magnet. This is called "diametrically magnetised".

See illustration.
[image: "axially magnetised" compared with "diametrically magnetised"]