# Are stator magnets in brushed DC motors radially magnetised?

Tags: motors, electromagnetism

In an electric motor like this one, are the stator magnets radially magnetised, as in, each of the two magnets has opposite poles on the inside and outside diameter?

[image]

Comment: In permanent magnet or even electromagnet DC machines, the polarities don't cancel each other out. They amplify each other, This kind of motors are really cheap , maybe three for a buck, buy some open them up, play with them, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find a picture on the web, but -- yes.  One is north on the inside and south on the outside, the other is south on the inside and north on the outside (so pay attention if you have a pile of taken-apart motors that you're reassembling!).  The steel can of the motor helps to convey the flux between the outside poles of the magnets, which increases the motor's torque -- this is why some of the larger "can" motors have an extra ring around the outer case right where the magnets are located.

Comment: It is considerably less work to just look at a picture on the web, so would have done that if I could have done that. All images show just magnetic monopoles (which do not exist, so), none show two radially magnetized magnets with opposite poles on the inside and outside diameter.