# Diametrically magnetised ring magnet, opposite poles on the inside?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am wondering about the magnetic field on the inside of hollow magnets. As an example, will use a ring magnet. In a diametrically magnetised ring magnet, does the magnet have the same pole on the inside and outside diameter, like this?

[image]

Or, does it have opposite poles, like this?

[image]

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/28294/10902, also have you started examining some motors as suggested in a reply to one of your posts?

Comment: yes that question was answered with that stator magnets are radially magnetised. if diametrically magnetised ring magnet has opposite polarities on inside and outside diameter, it seems like a valid question, the schematic images always show them as having same polarity on inside as outside.

Answer (score 1):

The first ring is barely useful, overly simplified, and certainly not representive of a real magnetic field.

The second ring is possible but there is another option. Instead of the center being magnetic,  the fields enter one side and are mostly  conducted through the material to the other side and exit the magnet as seen here [alternate example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Gramme_Ring_Armature_-_Minimal_Core_Penetration.jpg).